# Вопрос по строкам

Tags: c, строки

Доброе утро, у меня есть код, который считаем частоту встречаемости слова в строке, но я не могу понять для чего нужен while. Объясните пожалуйста.
Вот код:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"
#define STR_SIZE  300
#define DELIM " ,.!?:;()\t\n"

int main()
{
    char *words[100];
    int nWords = 0;
    char str[STR_SIZE] = "", *p = NULL, *pp = NULL;

    printf("Text: ");
    fgets(str, STR_SIZE, stdin);

    p = strtok_s(str, DELIM, &pp);
    while (p && nWords < 100)
    {
        words[nWords++] = p;
        p = strtok_s(NULL, DELIM, &pp);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nWords; i++)
    {
        int k = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < nWords; j++)
        {
            if (j == i)
            {
                k = 1;
            }
            else if (strcmp(words[i], words[j]) == 0)
            {
                if (j < i)
                    break;
                else
                    k++;
            }
        }
        if (k > 0)
            printf("%-15s: %d\n", words[i], k);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Начать можно с того, что функция `strtok_s` *находит следующий токен в строке байтов с завершающим нулем, на которую указывает str. Символы-разделители идентифицируются строкой байтов с завершающим нулем, на которую указывает разделитель.* ([отсюда](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok)). То есть, по сути, ищет следующее слово в строке и, в Вашем случае, кладёт указатель на это слово в переменную `p`. Если слов больше нет, в `p` кладётся `NULL`.

Теперь, чтобы Вам было немного понятнее, перепишу цикл более подробно (мой код делает то же самое, что и Ваш, просто операции более разделены):

```cpp
    p = strtok_s(str, DELIM, &pp);
    while ((p != NULL) && (nWords < 100)) // Пока слова не закончились и найдено меньше 100 слов
    {
        words[nWords] = p; // Кладём очередное слово в массив
        nWords++; // Наращиваем колчисетво найденных слов
        p = strtok_s(NULL, DELIM, &pp); // В p кладём указатель на следующее слово или NULL, если слова закончились
    }
```

То есть цикл ищет все слова (максимум 100) и складывает их в массив `words`.